# Domain literals not allowed Issue in Spring Mail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send email using **Spring Boot / Spring Mail**:

My Configuration is as follows:

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Properties :**

```
spring.mail.host=mail.XXX.com
spring.mail.username=XXX@XXX.com
#spring.mail.port=26
spring.mail.password=XXXXX
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=true
```

**And Mail Service is as Below:**

```
@Service
public class EmailServiceImpl implements EmailService {


    private  JavaMailSender sender;

    @Autowired
    public EmailServiceImpl(JavaMailSender sender){
        this.sender = sender;
    }



    public void processEmailRequest(EmailDetails emailDetails) throws Exception{
        MimeMessage message = sender.createMimeMessage();
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message,true);
        helper.setTo(emailDetails.getEmailTo());
        helper.setText("text/html",emailDetails.getEmailBody());
        helper.setSubject(emailDetails.getEmailSubject());

        if(emailDetails.getEmailCC()!= null){
            helper.setCc(emailDetails.getEmailCC());
        }

       try {
           System.err.println(">>>>>>>>  Approaching Sender.");
           sender.send(message);
           //sender.se
        } catch (Exception e) {
           System.err.println("SMTP : UNKNOWN ERROR" + e);
        }

    }


}
```

At this point I am getting following error:

```
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 <pramod-j@[192.168.10.34]>: domain literals not allowed
;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSenderFailedException: 501 <pramod-j@[192.168.10.34]>: domain literals not allowed
; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 501 <pramod-jazz@[192.168.101.4]>: domain literals not allowed
```

;

Comment: It looks like it's your server that's rejected the domain literal.  You mean need to contact your server vendor.  Of course, better not to use a domain literal.

Answer (score 4):

please add `helper.setFrom("<from@address>")` it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Disable your antivirus web shield and mail protection, and follow @btinsae solution helper.setFrom("sender-email-here@xyz.xyz") its worked for me, thanks.